# How to set the body of an email to a string containing multibyte characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, cjk

When I try to modify the body of a parsed email message, the resulting message is encoded wrongly. This is a minimal example:

```
raw_message = '''From: user@example.org
To: john@example.com
Subject: Happy new year

Please submit your 50000 word paper tomorrow.
'''

import email
from email import policy

msg = email.message_from_string(raw_message, policy=policy.default)
msg.set_content('天地玄黃宇宙洪荒')
print(msg)
```

This prints:

```
From: user@example.org
To: john@example.com
Subject: Happy new year
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0

5aSp5Zyw546E6buD5a6H5a6Z5rSq6I2SCg==
```

The encoding is wrong and the Chinese characters are not displayed. How can I set the contents of an EmailMessage to a string containing multibyte characters (such as CJK characters)?

Python version: Python 3.6.8

Comment: `msg.get_payload()` can you print this? and did you send the email to test?

Comment: did you send email to see how it looks when you receive it? It can be good text but encoded and other program may decode it correctly.

Comment: using `print(base64.b64decode('5aSp5Zyw546E6buD5a6H5a6Z5rSq6I2SCg==').decode())` I get `天地玄黃宇宙洪荒`

Comment: BTW: as I know (for historical reason) mail sends 7-bit values so it has to encode/decode values bigger then 127 and this is why it has to send your text as `5aSp5Zyw546E6buD5a6H5a6Z5rSq6I2SCg==`